# bundle config in a Capistrano task cannot find Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to add a configuration parameter in `deploy.rb` so that the `pg` gem builds correctly:

```
before "bundle:install" do
  run "ls -l #{fetch(:latest_release)}/Gemfile"
  run "bundle config  --local --gemfile=#{fetch(:latest_release)}/Gemfile build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config"
end
```

In the output, the diagnostic code added clearly shows the presence of a non-empty Gemfile:

```
  * executing `bundle:install'
    triggering before callbacks for `bundle:install'
  * executing "ls -l /apps/my_app/releases/20121008195429/Gemfile"
    servers: ["my_server.com"]
    [my_server.com] executing command
 ** [out :: my_server.com] -rw-r--r-- 1 webapp webapp 1291 Oct  5 22:34 /apps/my_app/releases/20121008195429/Gemfile
    command finished in 157ms
  * executing "bundle config  --local --gemfile=/apps/my_app/releases/20121008195429/Gemfile build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config"
    servers: ["my_server.com"]
    [my_server.com] executing command
 ** [out :: my_server.com] Could not locate Gemfile
```

I get the same result if I use `--global` vice `--local`.  If I remove the `global`/`local` flag, I get a different error:

```
** [out :: my_server.com] Invalid scope --gemfile=/apps/my_app/releases/20121008194937/Gemfile given. Please use --local or --global.
```

There seems to be a global configuration or context that is confusing the situation.  How can I make `bundle config` see my `Gemfile`?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In contrast to the `--gemfile` flag used in the `bundle install` command, the flag in `bundle config` only identifies the **name** of the Gemfile:

```
# man bundle-config
...
gemfile (BUNDLE_GEMFILE)
The name of the file that bundler should use as the Gemfile. This location of this file
also sets the root of the project, which is used to resolve relative paths in the Gemfile,
among other things. By default, bundler will search up from the current working directory
until it finds a Gemfile.
```

I fixed the problem by cd'ing to that directory first:

```
run "cd #{fetch(:latest_release)} && bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config"
```

More info:
http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html & http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: everytime there's a bundle config question, it's ALWAYS pg-config that's the culprit. Why?!!